# Nginx block specific directory to one country

Tags: nginx, geoip

I'm using Nginx and GeoIP to block certain countries (to the whole site).
Is it possible to block just one specific directory?

This way:

> www.domain.com/
>  Everyone can access
>  www.domain.com/**ES**
>   ***Only*** spanish IP's can access, no one else.
>  www.domain.com/**OTHER**
>   ***Everyone*** can access OTHER except China.

(Countries used merely as an example)
Thank you.

*And yes, I am aware that GeoIP isn't always accurate, but helps a lot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ngx_http_access_module` and `ngx_http_geo_module`.

```
location /ES {
    # Enter the Allowed IP blocks
    allow x.x.x.x;
    deny all;
}
location /OTHER {
    # Enter the Denied IP blocks
    deny x.x.x.x.;
    allow all;
}
```

Source:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html